# Efficient way of combining subsetting and combn

Tags: r

my question is about a fast and efficient way of constructing something like a "combn by" function, combined with a problem of merging two datasets. My data roughly looks like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(c(1, 1, 1, 2), c("A", "B", "C", "A"))
colnames(DF) <- c("ID", "Classification")
DF
  ID Classification
1  1              A
2  1              B
3  1              C
4  2              A
M <- matrix(data=c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6), nrow=3, ncol=3)
colnames(M) <- c("A", "B", "C")
rownames(M) <- c("A", "B", "C")
M
  A B C
A 1 4 7
B 2 5 8
C 3 6 9
```

The result I want in the end is this (with or without still including the `Classification1` and `Classification2` variables, I don't care) :

```
RESULT <- data.frame(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A"), 
                     c("A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "C", NA), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, NA))
colnames(RESULT) <- c("ID", "Classification1", "Classification2", "Value")
RESULT
  ID Classification1 Classification2 Value
1  1               A               A     1
2  1               A               B     2
3  1               A               C     3
4  1               B               B     4
5  1               B               C     5
6  1               C               C     6
7  2               A            <NA>    NA
```

So in essence I want to tell R something like: for each unique value of `ID`, create all possible binary combinations of the factors in `Classification`, for each of these possible combinations look up the corresponding value in the matrix `M`, return a `data.frame` containing columns with `ID` and the respective list of `values`.

I've tried writing my own functions based on `expand.grid` or `combn` for the first part, and then `melt` the matrix `M` into long format, and `merge` based on the `Classification` variables. That entailed a lot of `subset`, `merge`, and then `rbind` again, so took way too long. I tried using `lapply`, I can't seem to make that work. My feeling is that there might be a smart way of doing it with `data.table`, however I can't make that work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Nils

Answer (score 0):

You could start by generating a function to operate on the matrix:

```
matrix.gather <- reshape2:::melt.matrix
matrix.gather(M)->k
```

This will give you combinations of the matrix rows and columns.

```
> k
  Var1 Var2 value
1    A    A     1
2    B    A     2
3    C    A     3
4    A    B     2
5    B    B     4
6    C    B     5
7    A    C     3
8    B    C     5
9    C    C     6
```

You may then want to `merge` `k` with the `DF` `by` `Classification`  like so:

```
merge(k,DF,by="Classification")

   Classification Var2 value ID
1               A    A     1  1
2               A    A     1  2
3               A    C     3  1
4               A    C     3  2
5               A    B     2  1
6               A    B     2  2
7               B    A     2  1
8               B    B     4  1
9               B    C     5  1
10              C    B     5  1
11              C    A     3  1
12              C    C     6  1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I want to restrict the combinations before merging, so that not all possible matches are created, like in your example. Since the row with ID = 2 has only one Classification, I want the programme to give me NA here, since there are no binary expansions of one classification. Also, as pointed out in the answer by @thelatemail , I want to merge on pairs of Classification (so A-B with A-B), rather than on single classifications (merge A with B).

Answer (score 0):

Roughly the same logic as the other answer, but I think this restricts the combinations within groups more appropriately:

```
merge(
  merge(DF, DF, by="ID"),
  as.data.frame(as.table(M), responseName="Value"),
  by.x=2:3, by.y=1:2
)

#   Classification.x Classification.y ID Value
#1                 A                A  1     1
#2                 A                A  2     1
#3                 A                B  1     2
#4                 A                C  1     3
#5                 B                A  1     2
#6                 B                B  1     4
#7                 B                C  1     5
#8                 C                A  1     3
#9                 C                B  1     5
#10                C                C  1     6
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to almost do what I want. Is there a way to (a) make the value be NA when there is only one value in Classification (like for ID = 2), and, more importantly, to tell R that the order of classification doesn't matter, so the Classification with A-B is the same as B-A, so that I only get 6 matches for ID = 1 during the merge operation? The matrix `M` is symmetric, so it will give the same numeric values anyway, but I want to avoid double-counting.